# Meaning of "covariant", "contravariant" in operator algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, terminology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am reading [The Novikov conjecture, the group of volume preserving diffeomorphisms and Hilbert-Hadamard spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02086), and I came across a usage of the words "covariant" and "contravariant" that I did not understand.

Here is the relevant passage:

> Generalizing the construction of $C_0(X)$, we define, for a $C^∗$-algebra
> $A$ and a locally compact space $X$, the $C^∗$-algebra $C_0(X, A)$ to consist of all continuous functions $f$ from $X$ to $A$ that vanish at infinity, equipped with the pointwise algebraic and $∗$-operations. This construction is covariant in $A$ with respect to $∗$-homomorphisms and contravariant in $X$ with respect to proper continuous maps, by
> means of composition of maps.

I wonder if the categorical meaning of the terms is intended, but as these words are so overloaded, I found it quite difficult to Google. Maybe $C_0(\cdot, A)$ is being considered as a functor from some category of topological spaces to that of $C^*$-algebras, and similarly for $C_0(X, \cdot)$?

Comment: Your guess is correct. $C_0(\cdot, A)$ is a contravariant functor from the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces with proper continuous maps to the category of $C^\ast$-algebras with $\ast$-homomorphisms. And $C_0(X, \cdot)$ is a covariant functor from the category of $C^\ast$-algebras with $\ast$-homomorphisms to the category of $C^\ast$-algebras with $\ast$-homomorphisms.

Comment: The precise way these functors act on morphisms is as in Martin’s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone illiterate in category theory, here is what the statement says to me.

When $\rho:A\to B$ is a $*$-homomorphism, this induces a $*$-homomorphism $\tilde\rho:C_0(X,A)\to C_0(X,B)$ by $\tilde\rho:f\longmapsto \rho\circ f$. This is "covariant", because it goes the "same way" ($C_0(X,A)$ on the left, $C_0(X,B)$ on the right).

When $h:X\to Y$ is proper continuous, this induces a $*$-homomorphism $\tilde h:C_0(Y,A)\to C_0(X,A)$ by $\tilde h:g\longmapsto g\circ h$. This is "contravariant", because it "reverses the order" ($C_0(Y,A)$ on the left, $C_0(X,A)$ on the right).